# AJAX Auto Complete Extender with Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am Very much new to C Sharp. In My project I am designing a search page where I have Text Box with AJAX Control Auto Extender, I am Using a Web Service to fill the Text Box (This is the first time I am Using Web Service I don’t know to what the Web Service will be used) when the User Types the Word in the Text Box. I had specified everything correctly, when I run my Program and type the Word there is no response.

This Question may look like a **Duplicate** Question but not I had googled out many time seen many blogs worked out with the Examples shown there but No Result. Somebody help me please,

My Web Service Code is,

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using SubSonic;
    using DataAccessLayer;
    using System.Web.Configuration;

   using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
   using System.Xml.Linq;
   [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
   [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
   [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
   public class Search : System.Web.Services.WebService
   {

     public void Autocomplete()
     {


    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components
    //InitializeComponent();
     }

     [WebMethod] 
   public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count) 
    { 
      if (count == 0) 
    { 
        count = 10; 
     } 
     DataTable dt = GetRecords(prefixText); 
    List<string> items = new List<string>(count); 

   for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
    { 
        string strName = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString(); 
        items.Add(strName); 
    } 
    return items.ToArray(); 
  } 

public DataTable GetRecords(string strName) 
{ 
    string QueryString;
    QueryString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings     ["IUMSNXG"].ToString();
    using (SqlConnection obj_SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(QueryString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand obj_Sqlcommand = new SqlCommand())
        {
            obj_Sqlcommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            obj_Sqlcommand.CommandText = "LRS_SP_CBFM_Sel";
            obj_Sqlcommand.Connection = obj_SqlConnection;
            obj_SqlConnection.Open();

            obj_Sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@animalCode", strName);
            SqlDataAdapter dt = new SqlDataAdapter(obj_Sqlcommand);
            DataSet ds=new DataSet();
            dt.Fill(ds);
            obj_SqlConnection.Close();
            return ds.Tables[0];
          }
       }

    } 
  }
```

My AJAX Tool Script Manager is

```
   <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Search.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

My Text Box and Auto Complete Extender is,

```
 <Anthem:TextBox ID="srchtxt" runat="server" AutoUpdateAfterCallBack="true" 
                Height="19px" Width="200px"></Anthem:TextBox>
            <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="srchtxt_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" 
                CompletionInterval="100" DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" 
                 ServicePath="~/Search.asmx" 
                TargetControlID="srchtxt" UseContextKey="True" 
                ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList">
            </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: I have posted AutoComplete using jquery - http://deepumi.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/jquery-auto-completion-with-multiple-fileds-in-asp-net-c/

Comment: @ Deepu In my place the Wordpress website is Blocked If U don't mind could U post Here ???

Comment: can you share your email address.. I can send you the working code

Comment: Can you try this link http://www.4shared.com/file/FvnCpJ6R/jQueryAutoComplete.html

Comment: you can remove your email id, I have sent it.. Please confirm

Comment: @ Deepu I will Inform You with a reply to that mail when I get It Thanks a Lot...

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because in code behind file for `GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)` you are taking two parameter while in .aspx page you are calling this method without parameter like simply `ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"`.
If you remove the parameter from `GetCompletionList()` your code would work.

I know you require parameter `string prefixText`. This variable `prefixText` is nothing but the value entered in textbox for fetching the data from database so that it will give you the data accordingly.
So instead of using this parameter value in query just use the textbox value like `select * from table where name like '%textbox.Text%'`